# When different metrics which induce the same topology have the same result

Tags: functional-analysis

For those important theorems in functional analysis, e.x. Banach-Steinhaus theorem, in the proof, we use the language of metric, but the result can be applied to any metric with the same topology on that space. So my question is if we prove a theorem by the metric language, when the theorem still holds for another metric inducing the same topology?

Comment: Depends: Did you use properties that are not determined by the topology induced by the metric? If not, then you have effectively proven the result for the topological space which is defined by that metric, hence it works fine for any other metric on that space (and if you don't actually need the metric to state the result, even if it has no metric defined on it).

Comment: @JustinBenfield usually u need to use completeness in these theorems

Comment: @89085731 for normed vector spaces one can show that if a space is complete with a certain norm, then it is complete for any other norm that induces the same topology.

Comment: Completeness can be rephrased entirely in terms of the topology of the space in question (think about what a Cauchy Sequence must satisfy topologically).

Comment: @JustinBenfield: No, completeness isn't a topological property. For instance, $d(x,y)=| \phi(x)-\phi(y)|$ with $\phi(x)=x/(1+|x|)$ defines a metric on $\mathbb R$ which gives the usual topology so that $x_n=n$ is a Cauchy sequence without limit.

Comment: @Jochen You are correct, however, the Banach-Steinhaus Theorem does not actually use the full power of the completeness of the Banach Space in it's proof, The minimally sufficient condition is that the space is a Barrelled Space: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrelled_space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Justin mentioned in the comments above, this really depends on what exactly you are saying about your space. If you use purely topological notions so that your argument is about the topology on your space, then any equivalent metric will give the same results. If you are saying something non-topological, then you're in trouble.

As a reference: Let $X$ be a set with metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$. We say that $d_1$ and $d_2$ are equivalent metrics if they induce the same topology. For more about this see the [Wikipedia page on equivalent metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics).

If $d_1$ and $d_2$ were equivalent metrics on $X$, then any subset of $X$ proven to be compact when $X$ is equipped with $d_1$, would be compact in $X$ equipped with $d_2$ and vice-versa. If $(X,d_1)$ were path connected, then $(X,d_2)$ w
would be path connected as well.

This does not mean that a proof using metric $d_1$ would go through exactly the same for $d_2$.

For example, it isn't hard to show that $d_1(x,y)=|x-y|$ and $d_2(x,y)=\mathrm{min}\{|x-y|,1\}$ are equivalent metrics on $\mathbb{R}$. So both yield the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$. But notice that using $d_1$, $\mathbb{R}$ is unbounded (as usual). On the other hand, using $d_2$, $\mathbb{R}$ *is* **bounded**! In the $d_2$ metric any two real numbers are never more than distance 1 apart.

So if you were writing up some argument about $\mathbb{R}$ and your argument used distance bounds at some point, you shouldn't expect that argument to work when switching to metric $d_2$.

Even if the result you were proving was totally topological in the end, your *proof* might not work when switching to this new metric.

The fact that there are multiple potentially useful metrics out there is at first a little disturbing but in the end it can be really helpful. Quite often inequalities that are difficult to prove about one metric are trivially proven about another metric. Using the "right" metric can greatly simplify arguments. But it's is only ok to swap out your "standard" metric for an equivalent one if you are only concerned with your space as a topological space (not a metric space).

Comment: Thanks. Just a comment, I think different definition of boundedness will have different result. If we define define boundedness as for any neighborhood $V$ of $0$, there exists $t$ s.t. for $s>t$, $A\subset sV$, then $d_1$ and $d_2$ hold the same boundedness

Comment: You could try to reconcile these types of "boundedness" but that's not how boundedness is usually defined. Plus your proposed definition makes use of the specific structure of the real numbers. The point I was trying to make is that *in general* "bounded" is not a topological concept.